# Deploying a web application to Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, intellij-idea, deployment

I want to deploy my web application (Tomcat 8) on Heroku.

I'm using Intellij IDEA, after clicking che Commit and Push button IDEA starts asking for Git Heroku credentials. I haven't got what to enter in fields.

[image]

I used the Dropbox Sync to try a deploy for my application, it ended up correctly but the app page gives an error. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should Heroku login credentials for pushing to Heroku.
More betterly you can refer to Heroku deployment doc and use terminal command for the same.

```
git push heroku master
```

Then it will ask for the login to heroku.
Otherwise you can first login using command :

```
heroku login
```

And whatever command for heroku run without login.
For these thing's you need to install heroku toolbelt.
Heroku firstly take the source code to heroku repository and then run on their server.

Hope this information will help you.

Comment: You can get the heroku login credential's by creating account on Heroku.